# Локальный поисковик на сервере

Tags: веб-программирование, сервер, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть сервер, на нем хранится куча справочного материала (pdf, html, txt, doc и т. п.) нужно чтобы все это добро искалось индексировалось и отдавалось через web интерфейс. Существуют ли готовые решения? если нет, то какой самый простой способ организации такого поисковика?

Comment: это сервер доступен из вне?

Comment: Конечно. Иначе теряется смысл.

Comment: тогда простым вариантом будет настройка гугла или яндекса на индексацию вашего сайта.

Comment: Такое решение нужно в корпоративной локальной сети. Не хотелось бы всему миру показывать эти данные.

Comment: я по этому и задал свой первый вопрос.

Comment: Больше всего приключений, скорее всего, будет с чтением текста из всех нужных форматов файлов. А поисковых серверов, способных на индексирование и поиск, полно, сходу назову ElasticSearch, Solr, Sphinx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в своих проектах использую поисковик от Apache - Lucene.
Lucene — это свободная библиотека для высокоскоростного полнотекстового поиска. Может быть использована для поиска в интернете и при решении различных задач вычислительной лингвистики. Например, Lucene используется как компонент в децентрализованной поисковой системе YaCy (свободное ПО).
Написана на разных языках: C++, Java, C#

Поисковик очень быстрый и гибкий, можно даже настроить его на поиск неточных слов и даже фраз, море тонких настроек под свои нужды.

Подробные примеры здесь:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/609980/Small-Lucene-NET-Demo-App